# Error installing scipy using pip3

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, scipy, pip

I am trying to install scipy on OS X 10.8.5 using pip3 as follows:

```
pip3 install scipy
```

but I get the following errors:

```
compile options: '-I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c'

gfortran:f77: scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.f

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmpc.3.dylib

  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.2/f951

  Reason: image not found

gfortran: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program f951)

sh: line 1: 15049 Abort trap: 6           /usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c -c scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.f -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.o

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmpc.3.dylib

  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.2/f951

  Reason: image not found

gfortran: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program f951)

I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c -c scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.f -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3/scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.o" failed with exit status 134
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling python3, pip and setuptools I reinstalled them all but still got the same error.

So I uninstalled libmpc and reinstalled it using homebrew and that worked.

```
brew uninstall libmpc --force
brew install libmpc
```