# Error installing scipy on osx with brew

Tags: python, macos, numpy, scipy, fortran

I'm trying to install scipy on my osx 10.9 machine using brew but the installation keeps failing:

```
administrators-iMac-3:sourcefind_python bill$ brew install scipy --default-fortran-flags
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Building with an alternative Fortran compiler
This is unsupported.
Warning: No Fortran optimization information was provided.  You may want to consider
setting FCFLAGS and FFLAGS or pass the `--default-fortran-flags` option to
`brew install` if your compiler is compatible with GCC.

If you like the default optimization level of your compiler, ignore this
warning.
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/scipy/scipy/0.13.3/scipy-0.13.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/scipy-0.13.3.tar.gz
==> python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95 install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/scipy/0.13.3_1
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.8.3/f951
  Reason: image not found
gfortran: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program f951)
sh: line 1:  9597 Abort trap: 6           /usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -ff2c -O3 -funroll-loops -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c -c scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.f -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.o
error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -ff2c -O3 -funroll-loops -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c -c scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.f -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dfftpack/dcosqb.o" failed with exit status 134

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
  https://github.com/samueljohn/homebrew-python/issues
```

I have gcc installed which is supposed to contain gfortran:

```
administrators-iMac-3:sourcefind_python bill$ brew install gfortran
Error: No available formula for gfortran
GNU Fortran is now provided as part of GCC, and can be installed with:
  brew install gcc

administrators-iMac-3:sourcefind_python bill$ brew install gcc
Warning: gcc-4.8.3_1 already installed
```

should be there:

```
administrators-iMac-3:sourcefind_python bill$ gfortran
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue, you have to use another version of `gfortran`. A detailed explaination is given [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues/26#issuecomment-15877644).

You may also want to try installing using the .dmg installer availble [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/)

Comment: This shouldn't have been necessary; scipy generally works fine with brewed gfortran (from the gcc formula). There is a suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932013/error-installing-scipy-using-pip3 to reinstall libmpc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's having trouble with the fortran compiler. When I use OSX and Homebrew for SciPy, I usually also install gfortran to compile the fortran files in SciPy.

Try doing:

```
brew install gfortran
```

And then trying again.

Comment: Thanks, I should have gfortran installed through brew install gcc (i think) is there any way to test?

Comment: if you run `gfortran` from the command line, it should respond that there is no/an improper input file. Otherwise it isn't installed or the system can't find it. Try this?

Also from personally experience I had to install gfortran separately. I believe this is because when installing gcc it allows gcc to compile fortran files, but SciPy is looking for gfortran specifically.

Comment: Alright, so it's not that. I'm assuming you've tried it without the default fortran flags option?